qualys unauthenticated scan - deprecated mac's found
Is there a way to permanently remove deprecated mac's from OpenSHH package?
I just setup fresh ubuntu-24.04.1-live-server on a vm for test/evaluation purpose and attempted to run a unauthenticated scan against it - scan identified one finding which is related to usage of deprecated mac's, here is the detailed finding:
**Threat - "The SSH protocol (Secure Shell) is a method for secure remote login from one computer to another.
The target is using deprecated SHA1 cryptographic settings to communicate."
Solution - "Avoid using deprecated cryptographic settings.
Use best practices when configuring SSH.
Refer to NIST Retires SHA-1 Cryptographic Algorithm (SSH) (https://www.nist.gov/news-events/news/2022/12/nist-retires-sha-1-cryptographic-algorithm) .
Settings currently considered deprecated:
1.Key exchange algorithms:
diffie-hellman-group1-sha1, rsa1024sha1, diffie-hellman-group14-sha1, diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1, gss-gex-sha1-, gss-group1-sha1- and gss-group14-sha1-*.
2.MAC:
hmac-sha1, hmac-sha1-96, hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com, hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com
Results - "Type Name
MAC hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com
MAC hmac-sha1#"**
I logged onto the box and can see that OpenSSh package does uses deprecated mac (before) - root@ubuntu-sandbox:~# sshd -T | grep macs macs umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1 root@ubuntu-sandbox:~#
I have since implemented the fix which is discussed here by adding a conf file and ignoring the deprecated macs:
    root@appraps-ubuntu-sandbox:/etc/ssh/sshd_config.d# cat 60-remove-deprecated-insecure-macs.conf
MACs -hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com

(after) root@ubuntu-sandbox:/etc/ssh/sshd_config.d# sshd -T | grep macs macs umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512 root@ubuntu-sandbox:/etc/ssh/sshd_config.d#
though above steps might have disabled the deprecated mac - unauthenticated qualys rerun still identifies same issue. Is there a way for me to fix this permanently?
